# Flask: Interpolating new attributes in request context for testing

Tags: python, flask, request, pytest, middleware

I have a middleware that adds an attribute to the request object.

```
# middleware.py
from flask import request

...

def middleware():
    # some logic..
    result = api_call(processed_auth_token)    
    setattr(request, "result", result)
```

I use this attribute as part of the logic in my router

```
# routes.py
@app.route('/my_route')
@middleware
def simple_route():
    ...
    # use request.result here...
```

During testing, I don't want to go through the hassle of generating token and calling api_call (also for practical reasons since my deployment pipeline has no access to the internet). I want to be able to append different values to my result attribute during testing. So given a test scenario like the following

```
# test_simple_route.py
...
def test_simple_route(client):
    # client is in the context of test_client
    response = client.get('/my_route')
    ...
```

How do I set "result" attribute in the request object (from flask) in the get request above? I've tried using `test_request_context`, but the request end up in a different context than the client. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Making the request through the test client sets up a new request context.

You can call the view function directly after setting up your request context to test the middleware like so:

```py
import flask

def test_simple_route(app):
    with app.test_request_context():
        setattr(flask.request, "result", "test-value")
        response = simple_route()
```

I strongly recommend using the [`session`](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/quickstart/#sessions) object for this usecase.
They allow for storing information from request to request per user.